# I cant create an inset on the face of an extrude

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm modelling a face from a cylinder and ive extruded some faces to create ears

When I try and add an inset to the ears it completely messed up

What am I doing wrong

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello please share your object here (and share the link it gives): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/51da7bf1bf944e68af79f9d4525c7c14

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have duplicate vertices in the area you are trying to extrude. Try Mesh>Clean-Up>Merge by Distance, then adjust the merge distance to get a good result. After this, to aid in the help of extruding and beveling, switch to object mode, then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select Scale to apply scale. Now select that face in edit mode and try inserting face again. It should work.

Comment: I'm not actually trying to extrude yet. Im trying to add in inset to the ear face that is selected.

Comment: @ Gezzamondo, Nate is right, you have overlapping vertices and it make the operation fail, you need to merge by distance to fix it. Also, inset is just an extrusion except it stays on the original plan of the face.

Comment: So ive merged the 2 vertix on the outer edge to centre. but the 2 connected to the main face still seem to be messing up - https://ibb.co/X7MqqHz